# Second-order autocorrelation function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, autocorrelation

I am trying to calculate the second-order autocorrelation function

`g(lag) = < P2 (m(t) . m(t+lag)) >`

for a given numpy array m where P2 is the second-order Legendre polynomial `P2(x) = 0.5 * (3*x**2-1)`. The average is calculated over all initial points `t` for all possible lag times `lag`.

I have written a simple function to calculate this function `g(lag)`

```
    def calc_tau_fast_build(vector):

    maxLag = numpy.int(np.floor(len(vector)/2))
    g = numpy.zeros((maxLag));
    for tau in range(0, maxLag):

        w = 0;
        tmp = 0;

        for t in range(0, len(vector) - tau):

            theta = vector[t] * vector[tau + t]

            tmp = tmp + 0.5*(3*theta**2-1)

            w = w + 1
            
        g[tau] = tmp/w 

    return g
```

This works just fine, however for large inputs the performance is rather poor.

I would like to replace the entire function with numpy.correlate if possible. In fact, without the `P2 = 0.5*(3*theta**2-1)`  part, I can get the same results, upto a normalization constant, with

```
res = numpy.correlate(vector,vector,mode='full')
res[numpy.int(res.size/2):]
```

I basically couldn't think of a way to incorporate the `P2` function into the `numpy.correlate` without playing around with the `numpy` source code. Could anyone please suggest a way to use `numpy.correlate` in this context?

Comment: I don't see how the code (with the P2 part replaced by an identify function) can be equivalent to `np.correlate(vector, vector, mode='full')`. They have different lengths, for starters.

Comment: Hi @Seb, I edited the question. Upto a normalization, ```res = numpy.correlate(vector,vector,mode='full')
res[numpy.int(res.size/2):]``` works just fine, without the P2